# How interface this C code to D?

Tags: c, d, phobos

How should this C be convert to D :

```
typedef const gchar* (*GModuleCheckInit) (GModule *module);
typedef void (*GModuleUnload) (GModule *module);
```

Is this correct ?

```
alias const gchar* function( GModule *module ) GModuleCheckInit;
alias void function( GModule *module ) GModuleUnload;
```

Comment: if you are interfacing to C functions you need to use `extern(C)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 1 should be

```
alias const(gchar)* function( GModule *module ) GModuleCheckInit;
//         ^     ^
```

otherwise the `const` will apply to the whole thing, making `GModuleCheckInit` not mutable.

Line 2 is correct.